# Limit alt-tab icons to current desktop in Dexpot

Tags: windows-7, virtual-desktop

I'm primarily a Linux user but I use Win7 at work. I really like the Linux multiple desktops functionality, so looked around and found Dexpot to duplicate it on Windows. One thing I can't seem to figure out though - on Linux, when I <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> through open windows, it only shows the apps that are open in the current desktop. So far, with Dexpot, even if I have an app open in only one desktop, when I <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>, it shows that app in all desktops.

Am I missing something in the configuration? I want to separate out my dev apps from communications, for example, and if I'm in my dev desktop, I don't want to see my email and browser apps when alt-tabbing to move from one app to another.

Answer (score 0):

It might be that you changed some option in Dexpot. I have installed Dexpot 1.6 on my Windows 7 and i don't experience the same behavior. When i open applications in one of my desktops and go on another virtual desktop and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> i see only the open applications on that current desktop. If you still have the same problem try playing a little with the Dexpot settings.

Answer (score -1):

Under **Settings** → **Switching Desktops** → untick **Keep all taskbar buttons visible**

Comment: I'm not talking about the buttons in the taskbar. I DO want all of my taskbar buttons visible in all workspaces. What I DON'T want is to have to alt-tab through 15 open apps, when only 4 of those are open in my current workspace.